# Windows phone wrapPanel does not exist error

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-toolkit

I have a xaml which has the following code.

```
<ListBox.ItemsPanel>
    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
        <toolkit:WrapPanel Orientation="Horizontal"/>
    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
</ListBox.ItemsPanel>
```

Now the error says that 
The name wrappanel does exist in the namespace clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls etc...

Any idea how to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

You need to add the namespace to the root element of the page and you also need to reference it in your project either directly from the disk or by using NuGet:

```
Install-Package WPToolkit
```

In your XAML add the following:

```
xmlns:toolkit="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Phone.Controls;assembly=Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Toolkit"
```

Comment: Of course you do, that doesn't come with the default Windows Phone project.

Comment: Do you know the exact name for the package used for windows phone 8? Is it there in Nuget?

Comment: Install-Package WPToolkit

Comment: I have it installed already for this particular project...Stil it says the error...Any other possible errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling the package, it worked

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because Windows Phone toolkit is only available for

`Windows Phone Silverlight Applications`.